# Outlook 2010 display category colors in Business Card View

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2010, contacts

I recently upgraded a client in my organization from Office 2007 to 2010. She uses categories extensively with her contacts as she has several hundred contacts. In Outlook 2007, her business card view colored each contact relative to their category color. I cannot find a way to make Outlook 2010 do this. Is it possible to get business card view in Outlook 2010 to color the cards based on category?

Potentially relevant info:
Client OS: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 32-bit
MS Office 2010 Enterprise
Our Exchange server is running Exchange 2010

Answer (score 1):

When in business card view you will see a menu item on the right of the ribbon bar called **categorize** this may be what you are looking for. It is visible in the last 2 screenshots on the link below.

[Outlook 2010 Address book](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/a-user-guide-on-outlook-2010-contacts/)